# PHP - File upload data is null (undefined index)

Tags: javascript, php, html

So, I need to upload the captured image and while submitting the form it throws the error that the `index is not found` but it is already present though.

The error caused is

```
Notice: Undefined index: photoStore in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ttgym/Files/dashboard/admin/edit_mem_submit.php on line 3
Could not save image! check file permission.
```

`edit_member.php` file

```
<?php
require '../../include/db_conn.php';
page_protect();

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $memid = $_POST['name']; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Edit Member</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css"  id="style-resource-5">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/Script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/dashMain.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/entypo.css">
    <link href="a1style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    
    <style>
    #button1
    {
    width:126px;
    }
    #boxxe
    {
        width:230px;
    }
    .page-container .sidebar-menu #main-menu li#hassubopen > a {
    background-color: #2b303a;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
    .img{
        width: 200;
        height: 200px;
    }

    </style>

</head>
    <body class="page-body  page-fade" onload="collapseSidebar()">
    <!-- <div><section> -->
        <div class="page-container sidebar-collapsed" id="navbarcollapse">  
    
        <div class="sidebar-menu">
    
            <header class="logo-env">
            
            <!-- logo -->
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="main.php">
                    <img src="../../images/logo.png" alt="" width="192" height="80" />
                </a>
            </div>
            
                    <!-- logo collapse icon -->
                    <div class="sidebar-collapse" onclick="collapseSidebar()">
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-collapse-icon with-animation"><!-- add class "with-animation" if you want sidebar to have animation during expanding/collapsing transition -->
                    <i class="entypo-menu"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
                            
            
        
            </header>
            <?php include 'nav.php'; ?>
        </div>

            <div class="main-content">
        
                <div class="row">
                    
                    <!-- Profile Info and Notifications -->
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 clearfix">    

                    </div>
                
                    <!-- Raw Links -->
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 clearfix hidden-xs">
                        
                        <ul class="list-inline links-list pull-right">


                            <li>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> 
                            </li>                           
                        
                            <li>
                                <a href="logout.php">
                                    Log Out <i class="entypo-logout right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <h3>Edit Member Details</h3>
            <hr/>
            <?php
   $query = "SELECT * FROM users u 
                               INNER JOIN address a ON u.userid=a.id
                               INNER JOIN  health_status h ON u.userid=h.uid
                               WHERE userid='$memid'";
   //echo $query;
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
   $sno = 1;

   $name = '';
   $gender = '';

   if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1) {
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
           // echo $row['image'];
           $name = $row['username'];
           $image = $row['image'];
           $gender = $row['gender'];
           $mobile = $row['mobile'];
           $email = $row['email'];
           $dob = $row['dob'];
           $jdate = $row['joining_date'];
           $streetname = $row['streetName'];
           $city = $row['city'];
           $zipcode = $row['zipcode'];
           $height = $row['height'];
           $weight = $row['weight'];
           $remarks = $row['remarks'];
       }
   } else {
       echo "<html><head><script>alert('Change Unsuccessful');</script></head></html>";
       echo mysqli_error($con);
   }
   ?>


            
            
    <div class="a1-container a1-small a1-padding-32" style="margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px;">
        <div class="a1-card-8 a1-light-gray" style="width:600px; margin:0 auto;">
        <div class="a1-container a1-dark-gray a1-center">
            <h6>EDIT MEMBER PROFILE</h6>
        </div>
       <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="a1-container" action="edit_mem_submit.php">
         <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
         <tr>
           <td height="35"><table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
             <tr>
               <td height="35">User ID:</td>
               <td height="35"><input id="boxxe" type="text" name="uid" readonly required value=<?php echo $memid; ?>></td>
               </tr>
             <tr>
               <td height="35">NAME:</td>
               <td height="35"><input id="boxxe" type="text" name="uname" value='<?php echo $name; ?>'></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td height="35">OLD IMAGE:</td>
                 <td height="35">
                 <!-- id="showImage" -->
                     <img class="boxx" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="200" height="200" alt=""><br>
                 </td>
                 <!-- <td><br></td> -->
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td height="35">NEW IMAGE:</td>
                 <td height="35"><br><div id="showImage" class="d-none"><br></td>
                 <!-- <td><br></td> -->
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td height="35">CAPTURE IMAGE</td>
               <td><button class="btn btn-warning text-white" id="accesscamera" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#photoModal">
                        Capture Photo
                    </button></td>
                    <!-- <td><button class="btn btn-danger text-white" id="closecamera">
                        Stop camera
                    </button></td> -->
               
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td height="35">GENDER:</td>
               <td height="35"><select id="boxxe" name="gender" id="gender" required>

                        <option <?php if ($gender == 'Male') {
          echo 'selected';
      } ?> value="Male">Male</option>
                                                <option <?php if ($gender == 'Female') {
                echo 'selected';
            } ?> value="Female">Female</option>
                        </select></td><br>
             </tr>
              <tr>
               <td height="35">MOBILE:</td>
               <td height="35"><input id="boxxe" type="number" name="phone" maxlength="10" value=<?php echo $mobile; ?>></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td height="35">EMAIL:</td>
               <td height="35"><input id="boxxe" type="email" name="email" required value=<?php echo $email; ?>></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td height="35">DATE OF BIRTH:</td>
               <td height="35"><input type="date" id="boxxe" name="dob" value=<?php echo $dob; ?>></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td height="35">JOINING DATE:</td>
               <td height="35"><input type="date" id="boxxe" name="jdate" value=<?php echo $jdate; ?>></td>
             </tr>

            <tr>
               <td height="35">STREET NAME:</td>
               <td height="35"><input type="text" id="boxxe" name="stname" value='<?php echo $streetname; ?>'></td>
             </tr>   
             
             <tr>
               <td height="35">ZIPCODE:</td>
               <td height="35"><input type="text" id="boxxe" name="zipcode" value='<?php echo $zipcode; ?>'></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td height="35">HEIGHT:</td>
               <td height="35"><input type="text" id="boxxe" name="height" value=<?php echo $height; ?>></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td height="35">WEIGHT:</td>
               <td height="35"><input type="text" id="boxxe" name="weight" value=<?php echo $weight; ?>></td>
             </tr>
             
             
             
             <br>
            
             <tr>
             <tr>
               <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
               <td height="35"><input class="a1-btn a1-blue" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="UPDATE" >
                 <input class="a1-btn a1-blue" type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"></td>
             </tr>
           </table></td>
         </tr>
         </table>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- </section> -->

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="photoModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Capture Photo</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                        <div id="my_camera" class="d-block mx-auto rounded overflow-hidden"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="results" class="d-none"></div>
                    <form method="post" id="photoForm">
                        <input type="hidden" id="photoStore" name="photoStore" value="">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning mx-auto text-white" id="takephoto">Capture Photo</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning mx-auto text-white d-none" id="retakephoto">Retake</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning mx-auto text-white d-none" id="uploadphoto" form="photoForm">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            
            
                    

            <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./plugin/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./plugin/webcamjs/webcam.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html> 

<?php
} else {
}
?>
```

`main.js` file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Webcam.set({
        width: 240,
        height: 160,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90
    });

   
    $('#accesscamera').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Webcam.reset();
        Webcam.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            $('#photoModal').modal('hide');
            swal({
                title: 'Warning',
                text: 'Please give permission to access your webcam',
                icon: 'warning'
            });
        });
        Webcam.attach('#my_camera');
    });


    $('#takephoto').on('click', take_snapshot);

    $('#retakephoto').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#my_camera').addClass('d-block');
        $('#my_camera').removeClass('d-none');

        $('#results').addClass('d-none');

        $('#takephoto').addClass('d-block');
        $('#takephoto').removeClass('d-none');

        $('#retakephoto').addClass('d-none');
        $('#retakephoto').removeClass('d-block');

        $('#uploadphoto').addClass('d-none');
        $('#uploadphoto').removeClass('d-block');
    });

    $('#photoForm').on('submit', function() {
        // e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'photoUpload.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == 'success') {
                    Webcam.reset();
                    // document.getElementById("showImage").src=""
                    $('#my_camera').addClass('d-block');
                    $('#my_camera').removeClass('d-none');

                    $('#results').addClass('d-none');

                    $('#takephoto').addClass('d-block');
                    $('#takephoto').removeClass('d-none');

                    $('#retakephoto').addClass('d-none');
                    $('#retakephoto').removeClass('d-block');

                    $('#uploadphoto').addClass('d-none');
                    $('#uploadphoto').removeClass('d-block');

                    $('#photoModal').modal('hide');

                    swal({
                        title: 'Success',
                        text: 'Photo uploaded successfully',
                        icon: 'success',
                        buttons: false,
                        closeOnClickOutside: false,
                        closeOnEsc: false,
                        timer: 2000
                    })
                }
                else {
                    swal({
                        title: 'Error',
                        text: 'Something went wrong',
                        icon: 'error'
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
})

function take_snapshot()
{
    //take snapshot and get image data
    Webcam.snap(function(data_uri) {
        //display result image
        // $('#results').html('<img  src="' + data_uri + '" class="d-block mx-auto rounded"/>');

        $('#showImage').html('<img name="imgStore" id="imgStore" width="320" height="240" src="' + data_uri + '" class="d-block mx-auto rounded"/>');

        var raw_image_data = data_uri.replace(/^data\:image\/\w+\;base64\,/, '');
        // console.log(raw_image_data);
        $('#photoStore').val(raw_image_data);
        console.log($('#photoStore').val());
    });
    Webcam.reset();

    $('#my_camera').removeClass('d-block');
    $('#my_camera').addClass('d-none');

    $('#results').removeClass('d-none');
    $('#showImage').removeClass('d-none');

    $('#takephoto').removeClass('d-block');
    $('#takephoto').addClass('d-none');

    $('#retakephoto').removeClass('d-none');
    $('#retakephoto').addClass('d-block');

    $('#uploadphoto').removeClass('d-none');
    $('#uploadphoto').addClass('d-block');

    $('#photoModal').modal('hide');
}
```

`edit_mem_submit.php` file

```
<?php
echo $_POST['uname'];
$encoded_data = $_POST['photoStore'];
$binary_data = base64_decode($encoded_data);

$photoname = uniqid() . '.jpeg';

$result = file_put_contents('uploads/' . $photoname, $binary_data);

if ($result) {
    $fileName = 'uploads/' . $photoname;
    insertDetails('cools');
} else {
    echo die('Could not save image! check file permission.');
}

function insertDetails($fileName)
{
    require '../../include/db_conn.php';
    page_protect();
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $mobile = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $jdate = $_POST['jdate'];
    $stname = $_POST['stname'];
    // $state=$_POST['state'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];

    $query1 =
        "update users set username='" .
        $uname .
        "',gender='" .
        $gender .
        "',mobile='" .
        $mobile .
        "',email='" .
        $email .
        "',dob='" .
        $dob .
        "',joining_date='" .
        $jdate .
        "' where userid='" .
        $uid .
        "'";

    if (mysqli_query($con, $query1)) {
        $query2 =
            "update address set streetName='" .
            $stname .
            "',city='" .
            $city .
            "',zipcode='" .
            $zipcode .
            "' where id='" .
            $uid .
            "'";
        if (mysqli_query($con, $query2)) {
            $query3 =
                "update health_status set height='" .
                $height .
                "',weight='" .
                $weight .
                "',remarks='" .
                $remarks .
                "' where uid='" .
                $uid .
                "'";
            if (mysqli_query($con, $query3)) {
                echo "<html><head><script>alert('Member Update Successfully');</script></head></html>";
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=view_mem.php'>";
            } else {
                echo "<html><head><script>alert('ERROR! Update Opertaion Unsucessfull');</script></head></html>";
                echo 'error' . mysqli_error($con);
            }
        } else {
            echo "<html><head><script>alert('ERROR! Update Opertaion Unsucessfull');</script></head></html>";
            echo 'error' . mysqli_error($con);
        }
    } else {
        echo "<html><head><script>alert('ERROR! Update Opertaion Unsucessfull');</script></head></html>";
        echo 'error' . mysqli_error($con);
    }
}

?>
```

edit_member.php file is called with a `member ID` and when I capture the image and the image is captured and I also tried to print the data value in console and it prints fine. But when it comes to submission it causes the error that the index is undefined

Comment: `while submitting the form`...which form? There are two on your page. Only one of them contains the photo field.

Comment: And calling `insertDetails` from the code which handles the photo update makes no sense, because all those other details are submitted in the first form, not in the photo form. It's not clear why you have a separate form for the photo to begin with, since it seems you don't really intend for it to be submitted separately.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" id="photoStore" name="photoStore" value="">` should be inside "form1" and you should be handling the "submit" event of that form with your Javascript (assuming you want to submit the data via AJAX).

Comment: @ADyson Yeah there are 2 forms but without the 2nd form I couldn't capture the image and I'm very newbie to javascript and PHP. Please help me resolve this!

Comment: @ADyson After making somechanges got the output thanks for your help!

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: @biberman added `photoStore` input to 1st form and it worked

Comment: Ideally you should post your updated code as an answer (with a brief explanation) to make it easier to search for, in case others have a similar problem. Pay it forward...that's how Stackoverflow works. Take the [tour] to learn more.

Comment: @ADyson For sure I will